# How do I solve this indexOutOfBoundsException in my server send/receive thread?

Tags: java, serialization, client, classcastexception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am creating a multiplayer game in Java with a server and multiple clients. Everything runs perfectly, until I press the Kick-button in the server to kick a client.

Error at receive thread of server, after kicking the first person who joined out of three:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
  > at networktest.Server$3.run(Server.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The pointed line is the **ois = new ObjectInputStream** where I receive *datatype* in the server receive thread. The server kicks the first person perfectly, but removes the second one in the list too, with an error of *java.lang.ClassCastException*.

**server receive:**

```
private static Thread receive = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        ObjectInputStream ois;

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list_sockets.size(); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
                    int receive_state = (Integer) ois.readObject(); // receive state

                                            ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
                    byte datatype = (byte) ois.readObject(); // receive datatype

                                            if(datatype == 2){
                                                ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
                                                ChatLine chatLine = (ChatLine) ois.readObject(); // receive ChatLine
                                            } else if (datatype == 0){
                                                ois = new ObjectInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
                                                DataPackage dp = (DataPackage) ois.readObject(); // receive dp
                                                list_data.set(i, dp);
                                            }

                    if (receive_state == 1) // Client Disconnected by User
                    {
                        disconnectClient(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) // Client Disconnected (Client Didn't Notify Server About Disconnecting)
                {
                                        System.err.println("Error @ receive:");
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    disconnectClient(i);
                    i--;
                }
            }
                            try {
                                this.sleep(3);
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }
        }
    }
};
```

**user send:**

```
Thread send = new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
        ObjectOutputStream oos;
        byte datatype = 0;

        while (connected){
            if (socket != null){
                try {
                    DataPackage dp = new DataPackage();
                    dp.x = Client.player.x;
                    dp.y = Client.player.y;
                    dp.username = username;
                    dp.charType = charType;
                    dp.walking = (byte)Client.player.walking;
                    if (Client.outputChatLine.line != null)
                        datatype = 2;
                    else {
                        datatype = 0;
                    }

                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(Integer.valueOf(Client.this.state)); // send state

                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(Byte.valueOf(datatype)); // send datatype

                    if (datatype == 2)
                    {
                        oos.reset();
                        oos.writeObject(Client.outputChatLine);
                        Client.outputChatLine = new ChatLine();
                    } else {
                        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        oos.writeObject(dp);
                    }

                    if (Client.this.state == 1) {
                        connected = false;
                        socket = null;

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Client Disconnected", "Info", 1);
                        System.exit(0);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
            }
            try {
                this.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**disconnect client method:**

```
public static void disconnectClient(int index)
{
    try
    {
        list_clients_model.removeElementAt(index);
        list_client_states.remove(index);
        list_data.remove(index);
        list_sockets.remove(index);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Firstly, fix the catch block in `disconnectClient`. *Never* catch bare `Exception` and just ignore it. Next, tell us which is line 186...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting some other thread to fill some data into `list_sockets` while you're `sleep(3)`ing. But you have no synchronization to ensure that this happens only while you're sleeping.

It could equally well happen that the other thread is updating `list_sockets` *simultaneously with* your own thread calling `list_sockets.get(i)`. And the ArrayList implementation it is almost certainly not written to have two different of its methods executing simultaneously in two different threads. For example, the other thread could be in the middle of resizing the backing array when you're trying to read an element, and then any crazy thing can go wrong, including the error you're seeing.

You need to learn about inter-thread synchronization. At the very least you need `synchronized` blocks to protect access to shared data structures. And while you're at it; look at `wait`/`notify` or some higher-level concurrency tools to get rid of that horrible 3-millisecond polling loop -- instead have the thread that drops work into the list explicitly wake up the worker thread.

Comment: I just found that the answer of ajon was not my answer indeed. Since I'm not that far in this socket programming as I thought, could you give me a little hint where to start?

Comment: @StefanSchouten: How did you learn Java? Your textbook (or whatever) ought to have a nice chapter of threads and synchronization that you should start by reading.

Comment: Intermediate java, I learned at where I study. This socketing, I learned at a YouTube tutorial. Even though I think I have the hang of it, I still don't really. But I do have a text book, Java - A Beginner's Guide. It has a chapter of Multithreaded Programming, is this where I should be?

Comment: @StefanSchouten: I don't know the particular book, but that certainly sounds like the title of a chapter you should read carefully before embarking on programming with more than one thread.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your time! And... I feel guilty I didn't think of checking the book before posting. I have it - why don't use it :) so, sorry for that.

Comment: @StefanSchouten: Don't feel guilty; you couldn't have known to check the book before you knew the problem you were having was a concurrency problem -- and it takes some experience to identify them. And beware that the subject is notoriously complex and easy to get wrong, so don't be satisfied with a solution until you're sure you know why it works.